# Pragma 8602 Warning in Razor Markup

Tags: c#, blazor

The following very simple Blazor component throws a Pragma8602 warning in Visual Studio 2022 and Net6.

```
@page "/Pragma8602"

<h3>Pragma8602</h3>

#pragma warning disable CS8602

@if (myList is not null)
{
    @*No Pragma8602 warning*@
    <div>Count : @myList.Count</div>
}

@if (this.listNotNull)
{
    @*Pragma8602 warning*@
    <div>Count : @myList.Count</div>
}

    @*Expected Pragma8602 warning*@
    <div>Count : @myList.Count</div>

#pragma warning restore CS8602

@code {
    private List<string>? myList;

    private bool listNotNull => this.myList is not null;
}
```

[image]

I understand why.  It's clever, but not half clever enough!

The question is: Is there a simple way of supressing these Razor mark-up warnings?  Am I half asleep this morning?

*While obviously not a show stopper, I hate seeing these warnings.*

I wrapped the code in pragma warning suppression mark-up without any real expectation that it would work - and it didn't.

Comment: not tried with VS2022 but previously I've used the editorconfig at the solution level to achieve muting warning/messages that are not used or specifically against company style guidelines (eg recently the simple switch statements and simple "using" statements). see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022 . Note - this can be used at multiple levels in the app structure, solution wide is just one option.

Comment: @AppPack.  Thanks, but I was only looking to supress the Razor (I'm not clever enough) warnings.  I'm not sure I can do that in editorconfig.  I've updated my question slightly to be more specific.  If the pragma warning directives worked in Razor I'd be happy enough.

Comment: you can set the rules for specific file types, not just .cs files and for specific directories (eg just your razor pages directory). Again I assume that this would apply to razor files if you specified it in the editorconfig but again havent done this myself in the version you are using. worth a try - additional page with info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options

Comment: Adding `#nullable enable` before the warnings and `#nullable disable` after the line disabled the warnings for me.

Comment: #CoolDeveloper.  I already tried that.  You must have something else enabled somewhere in your VS 2022 setup.  I've just stepped up to 2022 from 2019 so still tuning my setup.

Comment: _"Is there a simple way ...?"_  Yes, `@if (myList is not null)`. What is your point exactly, that it should interpret your expression property?  Where would that end?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Yes, but that's not the point of the question.  If I have say a generic loader component to show a spinner when you're display context is null (loading) with state passed in as a bool parameter, then you get the warning.  I just condensed my example code down to minimum to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the pragmas in code blocks so that it recognizes it as c# rather than just trying to compile it as text. Since an HTML page might contain the character "#" and in fact often does if it contains a style block or anything else that references elements by id which uses #, it would be annoying if that was specially escaped by blazor. They do it for @ but that's much less often used, since it isn't used for anything

```
@page "/Pragma8602"

<h3>Pragma8602</h3>

@{
#pragma warning disable CS8602
}

@if (myList is not null)
{
    @*No Pragma8602 warning*@
    <div>Count : @myList.Count</div>
}

@if (this.listNotNull)
{
    @*Pragma8602 warning*@
    <div>Count : @myList.Count</div>
}

@*Expected Pragma8602 warning*@
<div>Count : @myList.Count</div>

@{
#pragma warning restore CS8602
}

@code {
    private List<string>? myList;

    private bool listNotNull => this.myList is not null;
}
```

Comment: I missed this at the time, but spot on.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that there is no early solution so I'll close off the question as **NO**.

### Update

A little further down the road.  See @fatraccoon's answer.

Comment: In the file {}.csproj delete line <Nullable>enable</Nullable> or modify the <Nullable>annotations</Nullable>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings
Change the properties by a method and add attribute [NotNullWhen(true)

Comment: It's not a method.  you're comment prompted me to revisit this question and @fatreaccon's answer is correct.  I'll delete this answer shortly.